# User location won't come up in simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to app development and I'm trying to get the user location to come up in the simulator but I keep getting the **Use of unresolved identifier** error. I have looked at other questions, which are very specific to their own projects, and have tried to approach my own app in a similar way but to not avail. Any help,  por favor? Here's my code, and a link to a screenshot of Xcode.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //Map
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {   let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)


        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //This is where I get an error
         map.setRegion(region, animated: true)**
    }
```

> `Error: Use of unresolved identifier`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you need to on userLocation in xcode

Comment: have you set custom location in simulator? 

if no debug -> location-> custom location

set and try this

the region set before the location taken by the device. So you need to set after the lat long taken by the device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `let region:MKCoordinateRegion` is a ***local identifier*** inside your delegate method:

```
func locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations) {...}
```

This is why you are getting ***Use of unresolved identifier***. Make this `identifier` accessible throughout the class, the error will be gone. Like:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //Map
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    .......
    .......
}
```

**N.B:** But this won't let you see anything in the map. Best way to see any output from your `MapView` is to put `map.setRegion(region, animated: true)` inside your `delegate` method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.first
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MKCoordinateRegion` instance before `viewdidload` method
You can follow below code for reference.

```
class Test: UIViewController {
    var region =  MKCoordinateRegion()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are getting Error because**

1. the variable region inside **viewDidLoad()** method `do not have access` of **region** variable inside
   **viewDidLoad()** method

   ```
       //This is where I get an error
       map.setRegion(region, animated: true)**
   ```

**Solution** :

1. Make **region** variable global to class so that that can be accessed from anywhere you want to.
2. Instead of this line inside **func locationManager**

   ```
   let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation,span)
   ```

Use

```
    self.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation,span)
```

**Here is complete code That you can use.**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //Map
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    //global variable 
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()

    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {   let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

        self.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)


        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //This is where I get an error
         map.setRegion(region, animated: true)**
    }
//

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

And more important if you are using simulator then you have to enable location simulation.

Comment: How is this answer different from my answer?